# Not able to set content view

Tags: android

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity implements
    FensterPlayerControllerVisibilityListener {
        ListView listview;
        CustomListAdapter adapter;
        private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public static int currentItem;
        public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
        public static MediaController mediaController ;
        boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
        boolean pauseOnFling = true;
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
            System.gc();
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();

            int largememoryclass = am.getLargeMemoryClass();
            Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));
            Log.v("onCreate", "largememoryClass:" + Integer.toString(largememoryclass));
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
            videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
             mediaController = new MediaController(VideoActivity.this); 
            videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
            videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/165/video/father-and-young-daughter.mp4");
            videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/185/video/couple-on-sail-boat.mp4");
            videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/39/video/VID-20141231-WA0006.mp4");
            videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/26/video/VID-20141216-WA0004.mp4");
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
            listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, videoLIst));
            listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
             listview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
                        FensterVideoView videoView = (FensterVideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

                    }
                });

          listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
              private int mFirstVisibleRow = -1;
              private int mActiveItem = -1;

              @Override
              public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                  FensterVideoView videoView = (FensterVideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                   if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                       videoView.destroyDrawingCache();
                   } else {
                       videoView.buildDrawingCache();
                   }
              }


              @Override
              public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                   int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                  int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                  int lastvisiblerow =listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
                  if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
                  {
                      mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;

                      // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                      FensterVideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                      if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                      {
                          prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                          prevActiveVideoView.clearAnimation();
    //                      prevActiveVideoView.destroyDrawingCache();
                      }

                      // Start the video of the new active item
                      mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                      FensterVideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                      if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                      {
                          newActiveVideoView.start();
    //                      newActiveVideoView.buildDrawingCache();

                      }
                  }

                  FensterVideoView lastVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(lastvisiblerow);
                      if(lastVideoView != null)
                      {
                          lastVideoView.pause();
                      }

              }

              private FensterVideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
              {
                  int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                  View rowView = listview.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
                  return (rowView == null) ? null : (FensterVideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
              }

          });

        }

        static class ViewHolderItem {

                    TextView textViewItem;
                    FensterVideoView video;
                    ProgressBar progressbar;
                }

        public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private Activity activity;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;
            private ArrayList<String> videoList;

            public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
                this.activity = activity;
                this.videoList = videoList;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return videoList.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int location) {
                return videoList.get(location);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                 Log.d("in getview method:",""+position);
                 final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


                 if (convertView == null){
                      inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, null);

                       viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
                       viewHolder.video = (FensterVideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                       viewHolder.progressbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
                       viewHolder.textViewItem =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);


                       int pos;
                       pos=viewHolder.video.getCurrentPosition();
                       Log.d("current item position:",""+pos);
                        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

                 }else{
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

                 }

                 viewHolder.textViewItem.setText("Video"+position);
    //             mediaController.setAnchorView(viewHolder.video);
                 Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
    //             BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //             o.inSampleSize = 2;
    //             Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(videoLIst.get(position), o);
                 Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoLIst.get(position));
                // Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.videoviewexample/"+videoLIst.get(position));

                // viewHolder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
               //  viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(uri);
                 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
    //                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                         viewHolder.video.setVideoFromBeginning(videoLIst.get(position));
                         viewHolder.video.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                }, 100);
                 //viewHolder.video.start();
                 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                 viewHolder.video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                         public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer arg0) {

                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               viewHolder.video.start();
                               viewHolder.video.setBackgroundResource(0);
                               arg0.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Log.d("In onpreparedListener oncompletion method:",""+ mp);
                                }
                            });

                         }
                       });
                 viewHolder.video.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
                          @Override
                           public boolean onInfo(final MediaPlayer mp, final int what, int extra) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "On_InFO");

                             if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == what) {
                                   viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                 Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "" + what);
                             }
                             if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == what) {
                                   viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   Log.d("BUFFRRING END", "" + what);
                             }
                             if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == what) {
                                   viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                   Log.d("RENDERING END", "" + what);
                             }
                             mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Log.d("In setOnInfoListener oncompletion method:",""+ mp);
                                }
                            });

                             return false;
                           }
                       });
                  viewHolder.video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                           @Override
                           public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                               Log.d("Error", "------>error" + what + "/" + extra);
                               if (extra != 0) {
                                   Toast.makeText(VideoActivity.this, "Can't Play Video",
                                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               }
                               if (what == 100)
                               {
                                   viewHolder.video.stopPlayback();

                               }
                               if(what == -107)

                               {
                                   Log.d("in error -107","error");
                                   mp.release();
                                   viewHolder.video.stopPlayback(); 
                               }
                           if(what == 1)
                           {
                               Log.d("in error 1","error");
                               viewHolder.video.stopPlayback();
                           }

                               return false;
                           }
                       });
                        }
                }, 100);
                  viewHolder.video.clearAnimation();
                  return convertView;           
            }

        }

        public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
              ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
              String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
              return Uri.parse(path);
            }

        @Override
        public void onControlsVisibilityChange(boolean value) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    I am getting this error:

        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407): Process: com.example.videoviewexample, PID: 5407
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.videoviewexample/com.example.videoviewexample.VideoActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2649)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1082)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at com.example.videoviewexample.VideoActivity.onCreate(VideoActivity.java:69)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        07-29 16:37:54.615: E/AndroidRuntime(5407):     ... 10 more
```

I am getting this error in this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
```

but this layout is in all three layout large,normal and xlarge then what is the issue?

I am unable to identify the problem how I resolve this?

Comment: Can you post the complete error please?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the problem does not appear to be there. I think the problem is

A) you have incorrectly defined the layout name.  Try with to add another layout

Comment: This error is resolved but I am getting error at this line   viewHolder.video.setVideo(videoLIst.get(position), 10);

Comment: null pointer exception at this line how I set video for FensterVideoView?